# How can draw squiggly line below wrong word for flex RichEditable?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, spell-checking, tlf

I want to draw a squiggle line below misspelled word in a Flex Spark `RichEditableText` component.

Please help me , Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As for me, the question you answered is too complex to provide detailed solution here. But I can show you a couple of directions which can help you:

1. Use [Squiggly from Adobe](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/squiggly/) as a ready-to-use solution.
2. Implement [these steps](http://forums.adobe.com/message/2773334#2773334) to have your custom Squiggly like solution. As for me this is a pretty nice solution which can be implemented with some changes and deep diving into TLF (I've personally successfully implemented it in a commercial project about a year ago).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank u so much for ur reply,

Currently adobe latest squiggly realse 0.6 is not supported arabic language, I have implmented whole solution except this suquiggly line below wrong word.

I implemented JAVA Jazzy Spell check engine and getting result from java, i want to draw squiggly line like in MS word or in adobe squiggly solution.

Comment: @anjum All you need is to get text line, localize word boundaries with it and draw squiggly line on this line. You can use the way 2 I've provided for it.

Comment: can you guide me please how can i localize word boundaries?